# Dynamic default arguments in python functions

Tags: python

I have a need for functions with default arguments that have to be set at function runtime (such as empty lists, values derived from other arguments or data taken from the database) and I am currently using the following pattern to deal with this:

```
def foo(bar, baz=None):
    baz = baz if baz else blar()
    # Stuff
```

Where `blar()` gives the proper default value of `baz` which might change during execution. However, the `baz = baz if baz else ...` line strikes me as inelegant. Does anyone else have a better method of avoiding the one-time binding of default function arguments? Small, cross-platform libraries installable by pip are acceptable replacements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, that's pretty much it. Usually you test for `is None` so you can safely pass in falsey values like `0` or `""` etc.

```
def foo(bar, baz=None):
    baz = baz if baz is not None else blar()
```

The old fashioned way is the two liner. Some people may prefer this

```
def foo(bar, baz=None):
    if baz is None:
        baz = blar()
```

Comment: The old-fashioned way avoids an unnecessary reassignment when `baz` is not `None`.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace

```
baz = baz if baz else blar()
```

with

```
baz = baz or blar()
```

if you're still happy with just testing for falsy values instead of `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
pip install dynamic-default-args
```

It is somewhat similar to other hacks, just more elegant.
The idea is to have a container class for dynamic default arguments, and a decorator that uses introspection to acquire the decorated function's signature, then generate a dedicated wrapper for it.
For example, with this function:

```py
from dynamic_default_args import dynamic_default_args, named_default

@dynamic_default_args(format_doc=True)
def foo(a, b=named_default(name='b', value=5),
        /,
        c=named_default(name='c', value=object),
        *d,
        e=1e-3, f=named_default(name='f', value='will it work?'),
        **g):
    """ A function with dynamic default arguments.
    Args:
        a: Required Positional-only argument a.
        b: Positional-only argument b. Dynamically defaults to {b}.
        c: Positional-or-keyword argument c. Dynamically defaults to {c}.
        *d: Varargs.
        e: Keyword-only argument e. Defaults to 1e-3.
        f: Keyword-only argument f. Dynamically defaults to {f}
        **g: Varkeywords.
    """
    print(f'Called with: a={a}, b={b}, c={c}, d={d}, e={e}, f={f}, g={g}')
```

As you may know, Python has 5 kinds of arguments classified by their positions relative to the syntax's `/`, `*`, and `**`:

```py
def f(po0, ..., /, pok0, ..., *args, kw0, kw1, ..., **kwargs):
      ----------   --------    |     --------------    |
      |            |           |     |                 |
      |            Positional- |     |             Varkeywords
      |            or-keyword  |     Keyword-only
      Positional-only        Varargs
```

We generate a string expression `expr` that contains the definition of a wrapping function, and call the original function with arguments depending on their type following the above rule. Its content should look something like this:

```py
def wrapper(a, b=b_, c=c_, *d, e=e_, f=f_, **g):
    return func(a,
                b.value if isinstance(b, named_default) else b,
                c.value if isinstance(c, named_default) else c,
                *d,
                e=e,
                f=f.value if isinstance(f, named_default) else f,
                **g)
```

After that, compile the `expr` with a `context` dictionary containing the default arguments `b_, c_, e_, f_` taken from the signature of `foo`, the function `func=foo`, and our defined class `named_default`.

```py
exec_locals = {}
exec(compile(expr, '<foo_wrapper>', 'exec'), context, exec_locals)
wrapper = functools.wraps(func)(exec_locals[wrapper_alias])
```

All of these are executed at the beginning (not lazy initialized) so we can limit to one more function call at runtime, and a minimal amount of type checking and attribute accessing overheads (which is a lot more efficient than calling another function to retrieve the default value) for each function.

The container's value can be modified later, and the function's docstring will also be automatically reformatted.

```py
named_default('b').value += 10
named_default('f').value = 'it works'
help(foo)
# foo(a, b=15, /, c=<class 'object'>, *d, e=0.001, f='it works!', **g)
#     A function with dynamic default arguments.
#     Args:
#         a: Required Positional-only argument a.
#         b: Positional-only argument b. Dynamically defaults to 6.
#         c: Positional-or-keyword argument c. Dynamically defaults to <class'object'>.
#         *d: Varargs.
#         e: Keyword-only argument e. Defaults to 1e-3.
#         f: Keyword-only argument f. Dynamically defaults to it works!
#         **g: Varkeywords.
```

Modifying `foo.__defaults__` dynamically should also do the job and be more performant.

See more: [dynamic-default-args](https://github.com/inspiros/dynamic-default-args)

Answer (score 0):

A quick&dirty example implementation of something that might work:

```
class DynDefault(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.callback = callback
    def __call__(self):
        return self.callback()

def dyn_default(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        args = [arg() for arg in args if isinstance(arg, DynDefault) else arg]
        for k, v in kw.items():
            if isinstance(v, DynDefault):
                kw[k] = v()
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return wrapper

@dyn_default
def foo(bar, baaz=DynDefault(blar)):
    # problem solved
```

Comment: This solution is broken. By processing args, you are not lazy evaluating the dynamic default args, but any possible `DynDefault ` provided when you actually call the function.
A practical solution could be replacing `foo.func_defaults` with a descriptor object, however func_defaults can only be tuple.
Though subclassing a tuple, and overloading __iter__ and __getitem__ could keep us in play, a little analysis of CPython source reveals, that members of the `func_defaults` object are accessed directly in memory in the PyObject, not through newstyle class interface, thus this cannot be solved. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def getArg():
  try:
      return arg
  except NameError:
      return 0

def foo(x, y=getArg):
    y = y()
    print(y)

foo(1) # Prints 0 (Default)

arg = 7 # Set by argparse?

foo(2)           # Prints 7 (Dynamic global)
foo(3, lambda:9) # Prints 9 (Dynamic passed)
```